# "if (a() && b != null)" will "a()" always be evaluated?

Tags: c#

I have such code:

```
if (a() && b != null) {
    b.doSomething();
}
```

I need side effect of `a()` even if `b` is `null`. Is it guaranteed by C#? Or C# may omit `a()` call if `b` is `null`?

Comment: I would suggest splitting up the expression in two if statements, that way it is more clear to the reader that you intend a() to always run regardless of b. in fact you could remove a() completely from the if statement and put in front as a separate statement.

Comment: I think you are asking for a very hard to find bug... But yes, a() should always be evaluated.

Comment: @AndersK. i still need `if` before `a()`. i need to test result of `a()`

Comment: Consider introducing a variable: `bool aWasOk = a();`, `if(aWasOk && b != null)`. That eliminates most of the confusion, in my opinion.

Comment: Eric lippert has an interesting article around this subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx.  P.S. Side effects like this in your code are going to make for maintenance fun...

Comment: "side-effect" is worse then a code smell, it's a code shart. Please follow the above advice and fix your code!

Comment: The worst part about relying on the side effect of a() is that someone may later refactor your code to put something else in front of a(), not realizing that a() has a side effect you need to happen.

Comment: I agree completely with @AndersK. Why complicate the code for yourself and others when you come back to it a year from now?

Comment: I think such a variable creates confusion Kobi. I would assume that the value will be used more than once and start searching for the second one. This code is more clear. (Assuming 'a()' has a descriptive name)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Yes, `a()` will always be evaluated.

Since the condition is evaluated from left to right, `a()` will always be evaluated, but `b != null` will only be evaluated if `a()` returns  `true`.

Here's an exact specification reference for you, from the C# Language Specification version 3.0. My emphases and elisions.

> **7.11.1 Boolean conditional logical operators**
>
> When the operands of `&&` or `||` are of type `bool` [...] the operation is processed as follows:
>
> - The operation `x && y` is evaluated as `x ? y : false`. In other words, `x` is
>     **first** evaluated and converted to type bool. Then, **if `x` is true**, y is
>     evaluated and converted to type bool, and this becomes the result of
>     the operation. Otherwise, the result of the operation is false.

Comment: Just pasting the specification is a poor answer.  Since this was already the accepted answer, I added the answer to the top of the specification.  +1

Comment: Why is that a poor answer? When the spec clearly gave the answer in a readable concise way?

Comment: *poor* is a bit harsch, but StackOverflow can do better than copy-paste the spec. Explaining in Human English, linking to the spec (still missing that one)...

Comment: @Konerak: Could you please post your "Human English" answer for us? As a Hungarian, I think that snippet of the spec is perfectly clear and readable, and any programmer who doesn't understand it in this context should seriously consider starting a career where reading comprehension is optional.

Also, if the spec isn't clear on the matter, can clear answers be considered correct?

Comment: @GyörgyAndrasek: the spec is indeed pretty clear in this example, but his additions are too: he answered the actual question ('Yes') and used the variables/names from the question. People sometimes have difficulty applying a spec to a concrete situation when they're not used to reading specs. You are right: the spec should suffice, but sometimes for some people, it just doesn't right away.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, expressions are evaluated from left to right; so `a()` will always be called.

See the [C# language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (ECMA 334, paragraph 8.5):

> Except for the assignment operators, all binary operators are
>   left-associative, meaning that operations  are performed from left to
>   right. For example, x + y + z is evaluated as (x + y) + z.

Comment: This might be too petty, but left associativity works for `x + y + z` - it doesn't suggest that in `(x + y)` `x` is evaluated first or second. That would be another section `:)`

Comment: That's not petty at all, Kobi, this paragraph is irrelevant to the question! For completeness: if the C# spec doesn't mention anything else, this evaluation order would also be correct for `x + y + z`: `y`, `x`, `x + y`, `z`, `(x + y) + z`. In fact, if not otherwise restricted by the spec, paragraph 8.5 would still allow `z` to be allowed to be evaluated first; this paragraph is only about the evaluation order of the operators with regards to eachother.

Answer (score 17):

The condition is evaluated from left to right. So `a()` is always executed, but `b` *might* not be evaluated depending on the result from `a()`.

Answer (score 13):

`a()` will always be evaluated. `b != null` will only be evaluated if `a()` evaluates to true.

This is known as [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: +1 for providing the name for this type of operation.  I am upset you beat me too it.

Answer (score 6):

The left side of && is always evaluated.  The right will only be evaluated if the left is true.  So you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx):

> The operation
>
> x && y corresponds to the operation
>
> x & y except that if x is false, y is not evaluated, because the
>   result of the AND operation is false no matter what the value of y is.
>   This is known as "short-circuit" evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

The logical condition in your if statement is composed from two logical operators first is `a()` which it is evaluated always.

Answer (score 4):

a() will always be called as it is the first thing to check in the if statement, even if b is null.

Answer (score 4):

Boolean expressions may be fully evaluated or partially if the compiler infers that further evaluation will not modify the outcome.

```
if (a() || b()) c();
```

If you rely on the side effects of b(), you are not getting what you want if the specific compiler implementation does smart boolean evaluation. I am not  sure what the standard says about evaluating boolean expressions, but if you want readability of your source code, you better spell it out in full. It will increase readability.

```
if (a()) 
{
    b();
    c();
}
else 
if (b()) c();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the conditions are evaluated left to right, `a()` will always be evaluated. And since you have used short circuit AND (&&), if `a()` returns false, `b != null` will not be evaluated. If you want both conditions to be evaluated whether `a()` returns true or false, use `&` operator.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the best answer:

evaluation of `(x && y)`:
if x evaluates to **false**, y will not be evaluated.

evaluation of `(x || y)`:
if x evaluates to **true**, y will not be evaluated.

In either case the first operand is always evaluated. You got to be extra careful to have side effects in second operand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, But **"It is not important that your code *works*, It is important that your code is *understandable*"**.

I prefer do like this:

```
bool val = a();
if (val && b != null) {
    b.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the priority of operation you want. Yes it is evaluated from left to right that means a() always executed before the rest. If you want b !=null to be always evaluated exchange their position.

Answer (score -5):

&& condition run when both condition is true.

So a() function render when b not equal to null.

this is basic for all pro

Comment: please be clear and specific and relevant to what has been asked.